# Error: Cannot find module './ui/Button.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations - typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I am trying to build a monorepo using npm with apps and package folders. The package folder has a shared_library with a components folder that contains a UI folder with a Button.svelte file and a Button.d.ts file. The components folder also has an index.ts file for exporting the Button component and a package.json file for the namespace. Where as the apps folder has sveltekit app. Following is the directory structure

[image]

The shared_library folder also has a node_modules folder for TypeScript, a package.json file with a devDependency on TypeScript, and a tsconfig.json file with an "include" array that includes "**/*.ts". In the index.ts file, I am exporting the Button component as follows:

`export { default as Button } from "./ui/Button.svelte";`

But I get an error saying that - Cannot find module './ui/Button.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations.

The Button component is correctly rendered in the web_app when imported and used as a component, and the type checking also works in the web_app when I import the Button.svelte file in the page.svelte file.

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: @debugger: Tried that- tsc still persist the same error

Comment: is it possible to include the whole error stack?